# How to set wait cursor for a particular custom methods excuted in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

i have used code the below code is working

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
/* some code... */
scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
}
```

But i want the 'scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT)' code in my own method is not working, how to set wait cursor in my own method.

The below code i using,
For example:

```
public void ImportLocalBook(Scene main) {
/* some code... */
scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
/* some code... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any node available on your method, you can do it by

```
your_Node.getParent().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    setSceneCursor(parentScene, Cursor.WAIT);

above code to call the below method.. we can have below method in common place and we can access that code from anywhere if we can access class of below method

    public void setSceneCursor(Scene scene,Cursor cv)
{
scene.setCursor(cv);
}
```